# matplotlibのplot_surfaceを利用した3Dアニメーション作成時に動作が次第に重くなる

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

下記のコードにてmatplotlibのplot_surfaceを利用した3Dアニメーションを作成しようとしました。
一見うまく行っているようですが、次第に重くなっていきます。

おそらくどこかでクリアすべきなんでしょうが、うまくいきません。

ご教示願えれば幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

def update(i, x, y, z, plott, pst, figt, axt, cb):
   i = i - 7
    #plott[0].remove() # <-- この書き方はエラーになる(ypeError: list.remove() takes exactly one argument (0 given))

   for j in range(-10, 10):
      x.append(j)
      y.append(i)
      z.append(i ** 2 + j ** 2)

   x_new, y_new = np.meshgrid(np.unique(x), np.unique(y))
   z_new = griddata((x, y), z, (x_new, y_new))

   pst = ax.plot_surface(x_new, y_new, z_new , cmap="plasma")
   plott[0] = [pst]

x = []
y = []
z = []
for i in range(-10, -8):
    for j in range(-10, 10):
        x.append(j)
        y.append(i)
        z.append(i ** 2 + j ** 2)

x_new, y_new = np.meshgrid(np.unique(x), np.unique(y))
z_new = griddata((x, y), z, (x_new, y_new))

ps = ax.plot_surface(x_new, y_new, z_new , cmap="plasma")
plot= [ps]
cb = fig.colorbar(ps)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs=(x, y, z, plot, ps, fig, ax, cb), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: 「次第に重くなっていきます。」とは、実際にメモリ使用量が増えているのを確認された、ということでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、メモリの使用量を見たわけではないのですが同じ点数・形状で試してみた時に動きが明らかに遅くなったため、そのような表現になりました。

Comment: 確認してみましたが、放っておくとどんどんメモリの使用量が増えていき、同点数、同形状のものを一回描画したときに比べてメモリ量に差がありました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pst = ax.plot_surface(x_new, y_new, z_new , cmap="plasma")`の前に`ax.cla()`を追加してはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
うまく動くようになりました！大変感謝です！